# HowTo repair GRUB in triple boot with two encrypted LVM?

Tags: grub2, encryption, lvm

I setup Win7/DebianTesting/Ubuntu 12.04 as triple boot, Debian and Ubuntu each on an encrypted volume (with separate root and swap partitions).

Installation order: Win7 --> Debian --> Ubuntu, Grub was installed on `/dev/sda`, everything went fine, all 3 OS showing up in Grub UI and able to boot.

After an update with 12.04 (probably new kernel), Debian disappeared in Grub and so far I am only able to get Win/Debian or Win/Ubuntu showing up in Grub, according to these instructions:
[Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1807951)
[blog post: restoring GRUB for an encrypted LVM](https://stephentanner.com/restoring-grub-for-an-encrypted-lvm.html)

my partitions:
sda1 NTFS (100Mb)
sda2 NTFS (210Gb) Win7
sda3 extended partition where both Linux distros are installed into to LVMs:
sda5 boot (250Mb) for Debian
sda6 encrypted LVM (with separate Debian swap and root partitions)
sda7 boot (300Mb) for Ubuntu
sda8 encrypted LVM (with separate Ubuntu swap and root partitions)

with Ubuntu 12.04 liveCD I am able to decrypt and mount all partitions,
however neither Debian or Ubuntu boot partitions are recognized/useable to use chroot and to reinstall GRUB into `/dev/sda`

Comment: Did you try [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)?

Comment: yes, but only the option to fix MBR are active there. Options to fix GRUB are greyed out and fixing MBR ends with the result, that the laptop boots into windows immediately (which is ok), but booting with ubuntu-live cd will later result again in the same result as described above (either Win7/Debian or Win7/Ubuntu are in GRUB menu, but not all three).  I suspect it has to do with initramfs (what I have read also in forums) but i am not that advanced

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution:
1) reinstallation of Ubuntu followed by Debian
sda2 NTFS (210Gb) Win7
sda3 extended partition where both Linux distros are installed into to LVMs:
sda5 boot (250Mb) for Ubuntu
sda6 encrypted LVM (with separate Ubuntu swap and root partitions)
sda7 boot (300Mb) for Debian
sda8 encrypted LVM (with separate Debian swap and root partitions)

Debian testing has newer GRUB version 2.x than Ubuntu 12.04 (1.98) so this installation brought up Debian GRUB loader with all 3 OS recognized.

Before updating in Debian I decrypted and activated the Ubuntu LVM (but without mounting) and Debian again recognized all 3 OS.

Booting in Ubuntu: before updating the system the Debian LVM was decrypted and the volume group activated (same as before with Ubuntu during Debian update) and Ubuntu recognized again all 3 OS (such a relieve).

So each time before any update the other encrypted LVM needs to be decrypted and activated to avoid problems.